# Asset creation model in hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I have basic understanding of both model.There are two popular approaches to defining assets in most block chain solutions: the stateless UTXO model, where account balances are encoded into past transaction records; and the account model, where account balances are kept in state storage space on the ledger.

which model does Hyperledger Fabric support to create assets ?

is it handled by the sdk or the responsibility of the smart contract developer to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Developer handles definition of assets in the the chaincode. The values are then kept in world state storage which is actually different storage from the ledger. The ledger lives on the peer's file system and the current values of "accounts" aka key value pairs are stored in the world state which is database. Typically couchDB but can be configured to connect to other types of databases